# Decreasing sequence of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are measurable functions such that $f_1(x)\geq f_2(x)\geq\ldots$. (infinite sequence) and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=0$?

I wanted to apply the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) but cannot, because $f_i(x)$ is not necessarily integrable. So is there a counterexample for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{\chi_{[0, 1/n]}}{x} &: x \in (0, 1] \\
0 &: x = 0\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is $\chi_[0,1/n]$ the characteristic function that takes the value $1$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @PJMiller Yes! ${}$